# Why is C/C++ used by researchers to develop and test algorithmic trading strategies?

Tags: programming, high-frequency, c

I understand why compiled languages such as C/C++ are important for low-latency trading infrastructure. 
But I am curious why even researchers at the high-frequency trading firms also require a strong mastery of C/C++? Isn't Python (with the numerous strong packages such as scikit, pandas, etc) a better language for data exploration, data wrangling, machine learning and subsequently to quickly test out algorithms? How are these tasks achieved in C/C++?

Advance thanks for your time and help.

Comment: Is it perhaps not the case that they do use Python for these purposes, but as a quant at a trading firm you are expected to be able to both do data wrangling and machine learning *and* maintain and expand about infrastructure C++ code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plenty of HFT shops do *not* require C++ from the quants who are only involved in modeling. As you hypothesize, Python is sufficient for researching models. Your friend may simply be at a place that values tighter integration between research and engineering. Other shops will just have a Python wrapper to fetch historical data, obviating the need for C++.

(I personally handled both research and development in my day, so I wrote all the Python and C++ code anyway. My experience is not common.)

As mentioned in a comment, there is [C++ Design Patterns and Derivatives Pricing](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521721628) by the late [Mark Joshi](https://quant.stackexchange.com/users/1809/mark-joshi). And there are other books recommended in [this answer](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/52977/35).

Comment: absolutely, moreover C has been there forever

Answer (score 1):

C/C++ are low level languages in comparison with Python. Moreover, Python is scripting language. By nature, scripting languages are slow becuase they have to be interpreted. As there is a requirement for the highest possible performance in HFT, compiled languages are natural choice.

Concerning libraries, there is also vast amount of maths libraries for C/C++ as these (mainly C) were historically used in scientific research.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Do you know of any book that explains how to use C++ for Data Science?

Comment: @vpy: I do not use C++ much in work, so I cannot give you reference to a blok but try to Google *C++ for data science book*. There are some links to Amazon.

Comment: @vpy More so quantitative finance than data science but I like the book C++ Design Patterns and Derivatives Pricing by Mark Joshi quite a lot. Very accessible book on C++ for people with a background in financial mathematics. The book is more so about implementing efficient, clean and reusable code, so probably more about building up infrastructure than testing out algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reach out to a friend working at a HFT place as a quant researcher. It appears that C++ knowledge is key to interact with the infrastructure (which is all written in C++). For example, when trying to conduct a research on Level 2 data, researchers are expected to know C++ to be able to use the C++ APIs to aggregate the relevant order book data into a csv format etc, and from there, the researchers can use Python (read the csv and conduct any analysis using scikit learn etc). And when pushing a signal into production, again its necessary for researchers to know C++ to be able to work effectively with engineers to deploy the signal.